# How to close GLFW window when we close QT application

Tags: qt, qt5, glfw

When i close the QT GUI i want the GLFW window to be closed accordingly.

For glfw we can query if window is closed or not by  glfwWindowShouldClose function.

Do we have anything like that in QT where we can keep Querying if the application GUI is closed.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TreeModel model;
    QTApplication w(model);
    int return_code = 0;
    QTApplication.show();
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Renderer", nullptr, nullptr);   // Create the render window
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("Not able to create GL Window");
        msgBox.exec();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GLenum GlewInitResult;
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GlewInitResult = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult)   // Check if glew is initialized properly
    {
        glfwTerminate();
    }       
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);      
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Do Rendering here

    }       
    return_code =  a.exec();
    glfwTerminate();
    return return_code;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a signal for that, emitted by the application:

[QGuiApplication::lastWindowClosed()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#lastWindowClosed)

It looks like what you want to do is intermangle the Qt event loop with your own loop. Here is a hint about how to do that from the Qt docs:

> To make your application perform idle processing (i.e. executing a special function whenever there are no pending events), use a QTimer with 0 timeout. More sophisticated idle processing schemes can be achieved using processEvents().

So this is how I would approach this:

1. Setup a QTimer that connects to a method that does rendering (if window should not close) and restarts the timer
2. Call a.exec()
3. In the method called by the timer, if window should close, call a.quit()

Comment: this function returns void can you please show me how we can use this function

Comment: I suggest you read up about Qt signal/slot mechanism then. It is basic Qt knowledge, I think it does not make sense to repeat it here.