# Why does the While loop inside the QT loop is not blocking the QT GUI

Tags: qt, qt5

I am using GLFW along with QT for an opengl application.

i have a while loop inside the main function.

Why the while loop is not blocking the QT GUI ?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    cont.SetName("RootItem");
    TreeModel* model = new TreeModel("RootElement", &cont);
    WavefrontRenderer w(model);
    w.show();
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Renderer", nullptr, nullptr);   // 
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GLenum GlewInitResult;
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GlewInitResult = glewInit();

    w.InitData();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.0);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        w.render();     
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    //return 0;

    return a.exec();
```

}

Comment: What makes you conclude that it isn’t blocking it?

Comment: @Darklighter i am freely able to click on button of the GUI and the buttons perform according to their signal and slots.

Comment: I should have got some freeze kind of feeling if the buttons where blocked.

Comment: what does `w.render()` do?

Comment: Try adding `QPushButton pb("Press"); pb.show();` immediately *before* `while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))`.  Can you interact with the pushbutton?

Comment: @Darklighter w.render has opengl rendering calls.

Comment: @G.M The button code executes once.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `"The button code executes once"`.  You can't interact with the button until `a.exec()` is called -- after the glfw loop has terminated.  Note that you've already been given good advice as to how to proceed with this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223151/6371123) to a previous question.

Comment: @G.M the answer from Darklighter sheds light why the code executes once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `glfwPollEvents` acts in a similar enough way to `QApplication::exec` such that (some) events get properly processed.
They probably both call `DispatchMessage` ([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows)) which then lets registered callback for a window handle the event.
But it might also be that both do additional bookkeeping which could make reliance on that error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using QApplication event pump at all, you  short-circuited on Moodle\glfw\Wavefront library event loop.

Qt's OpenGl support via `QOpenGLWidget` directly works with `paintGL` method which ought to perform all rendering and which is called from inside of event loop. If you're not using that, you'll have somehow combine two threads, which is problematic that both OpenGL pipeline and Qt main loop on some platforms are limited to be usable ONLY in main thread.

Comment: yes that is the problem i am facing initially all openGl rendering was been done in another thread but i realised that gl_deleteBuffers were not able to delete the VAO ,  VBO.

Comment: @Summit  wait, is that library Wavefront or some class you called WavefrontRenderer (e.g. because you render OBJs)?

Comment: That is a class which i have created.

Comment: @Summit perhaps you should abadon GLFW direct use and move that `render()` call to QOpenGLWidget's `paintGL`. Otherwise I don't know why you need Qt.

Comment: this class is derived from QMainwidow

Comment: yeah that is a fantastic idea.

Comment: @Summit that's too mysterious. Is it wrapper around QMainWindow with QOpenGlWidget inside? How you expect to run event loop if QApplication object left outside and .exec() never was called?

Comment: I need Qt for the GUI as the designer would be designing scenes( it is a 3d Modeling application)

Answer (score 0):

you are not even starting the Qt application event loop because you are not calling the a.exec() as your code is I side the while loop.
I'm no opengl expert but I guess the window you are seeing is the one rendered by opengl itself not a gl canvas inside you qt application window.